# Why does this Jquery plug-in Lag my webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, html, digits

I found this Jquery Plug-In on google to make element text have commas placed in the numbers:

```
$.fn.digits = function(){
return this.each(function(){
$(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") );
})
}
```

and to call it on an element:

```
$("#elementID").digits();
```

It lags my whole webpage when active. I found that this is the thing that is causing it by commenting it out and running the page again. When its commented out, it runs smoothly. Is there a way to fix this? A different script or plug-in?

Comment: Possibly you have lots of elements in `#elementID`

Comment: Usually it's because jquery runs after the HTML is loaded.

Comment: You can cache the objects: `$.fn.digits = function(){
  return this.each(function(){
    $this=$(this);  
    var newText = $this.text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
    $this.text(newText);
  })
}`